# Avoid element to be dragged in Draggabily

Tags: layout, packery, draggabilly

I'm using Draggabilly and Packery to build a optimized draggable layout as shown in this Codepen: https://codepen.io/rafaF/pen/MWjvjqO

I have some doubts about how to use Packery/Draggabily.

- The first one is how to convert en element "no-draggable", i.e., avoid to be dragged. I've achieved this by no initializing its `Draggabilly` instance, but I would like also to not be sorted when dragging others elements.
- In the other hand, I have not been able to set a fixed height on my Packery layout in order to limit how many elements fits in a column. My idea is that if you move an element to a column that has no free space, the most bottom element should be moved to the other column. I have not found any way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

There is enabled and disable switch in Draggabilly instance that you create. So just disable it if you do not need it.

The second part has to be manually solved becuase the Packery and draggabily would try to adjust in the same layout giving you best possible fit. If you want to limit the height then you have to set and run the ShiftLayout() on pakery. Ideally I would leave it to packery to determine the best layout.